# How to add HTML tags into attribute with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to set some HTML code with jQuery to html attribute.

Something like this :

```
$(".carousel").attr("data-dot","<button role="button" class="owl-dot"><?php 
include("inc/chart3.svg")?></button>");
```

but there is problem with escaping... How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Wrap code in `'` instead of `"`

Comment: Stuffing html into an element attribute is ugly and generally not necessary. Why are you needing to do this in the first place?

Comment: @charlietfl i need to make custom animated dots for owl-carousel, and the animation is made by svg file and this is made by add code into data-dot attribute

Comment: Hard to believe there aren't cleaner ways to do it

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extensive breakdown of all your options.

Both double and single quotes can be escaped with backslashes:

```
 $(".carousel").attr("data-dot", "<button role=\"button\">");
 $(".carousel").attr("data-dot", '<button role=\'button\'>');
```

Of course, you can also use single quotes inside of double quotes depending on the scenario (i.e., yours):

```
 $(".carousel").attr("data-dot", "<button role='button'>");
```

Finally, single quotes can also be placed inside double quotes:

```
 $(".carousel").attr("data-dot", '<button role="button">');
```

**EDIT**

A good way to play around with escaping strings is just plugging stuff into your browser console.

```js
console.log("Here is a \"quote.\"");
console.log('Here is a "quote."');
console.log("Here is 'another quote.'");
console.log('Here is yet \'another quote.\'');
```

Comment: And is there any way how to execute php code? <?php 
include("inc/chart3.svg")?> .

Comment: @kores59 You can't directly do this with JavaScript -- PHP has to be processed on the server side. However, if you place that `<?php include` in your `.php` file, that would work. Quick example: `foo.php - <script>var a = "<?php echo time(); ?>"</script>` would set a variable `a` to `time` when your page was loaded. Takes a bit of finagling, but you can do most things.

Answer (score 0):

Tidier if you did something like this:

```js
let $btn = $("<button/>", {
    "role": "button",
    "class": "owl-dot",
    "html": "<?php include('inc/chart3.svg');?>"
});
$(".carousel").attr("data-dot", $btn.prop('outerHTML'));

console.log('carousel: ', $('.carousel').attr('data-dot'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="carousel"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the php code in attribute is commented, so it won´t execute  "data-dot="<button role="button" class="owl-dot"><!--?php include('inc/chart3.svg');?--></button>"

Comment: i think that's stackoverflow's commenting system doing that to it - try the code.